# OpenMDAO 1.x: recording desvars, constraints and objective

Tags: recorder, openmdao

How can you get information about which variables are design vars, objectives or constraints from the information saved by recorders? It would be useful to print this information to a file to track optimization progress during a run. It looks like the `RecordingManager.record_iteration` doesn't really allow for this at the moment, since you only pass the `root` system and a metadata dict meant for optimizer settings.

Would it be possible to add an argument to the `RecordingManager.record_iteration` called e.g. `optproblem`, which is a dictionary with dictionaries with desvars, constraints and objective?

A simple OptimizationRecorder could then dump out column formatted files with the quantities for easy plotting during the optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something we have on our list of to-do's for the near future. Our current planned approach is going to be to augment the meta-data (already being saved) of variables with labels identifying them as des-vars, objectives, and constraints. Then you could pull that information out as part of a custom case recorder if you want. We plan on doing it this way because it doesn't require modifying the recorder's api at all. I think we'll have something like this implemented in the next month or so.

Comment: that would be great. do you have a new pivotal tracker that is also public like the old one? if so, I could avoid asking all these questions if a story has already been made for it.